# How do I intercept ALT-META_LEFT getKeyCode();?

Tags: android, keyboard

UPDATE:
I misread the reference.  The key code I cannot stop is ALT and META_LEFT

### I have updated the title of this post.  I am so sorry.

I have an app that uses a bluetooth mouse-presenter to control it.  I have intercepted all the buttons on the device except one.  When it is pressed, I get various things happening not in my app, like going to Google Play, or a pop-up asking what music player I want to use.  I have tried to intercept it but have failed.  Even test code that lets no keycodes through and just does a Toast lets this one keycode through.

The keycode in question is 57 and 117 which is ALT-MENU according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).

Here is the code can successfully intercepts any other keys except this one. For example, I can add a case for 24 and the up volume key on the tablet or mouse-presenter will no longer work.

```
@override // tried both with and without the override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke){
    int keyCode = ke.getKeyCode();
    if(ke.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(keyCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        switch (keyCode)
        {
            case 117:
            case 57:
            case 44:
            case 59:
                return true;

            case 30:
                Intent target = new Intent(this, StartLine2.class);
                startActivity(target);
                return true;
            case 19:
                new Thread(new Runnable() {         
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                 
                        new Instrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB);
                    }   
                }).start();
                return true;
            case 20:
                new Thread(new Runnable() {         
                    @Override
                    public void run() {                 
                        new Instrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);
                    }   
                }).start();
                return true;
        }
    }
    else if(ke.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
        switch (keyCode){
            case 117:
            case 57:
            case 30:
            case 44:
            case 59:
            case 19:
            case 20:
                return true;
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(ke);
}
```

What I would expect is that both 57 and 117 are not passed to the dispatchKeyEvent and would therefore do nothing.  However, as I said, they fire off some process.  It used to be Google Play but now seems to be asking for me to select a music player "Complete action using..."

Ideally I want to use that key for something useful but as a fallback just making hitting it by mistake not mess up my app would be an OK second choice.

I don't know what to do and would love to get some help on this problem.

Comment: @Tim  Can you comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to intercept

```
ownET.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        ...;
        return true;
        default:
        break;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
});
```

I would expect this to catch all key events...
sorry can't try myself since I cant get ALT-MENU...

Comment: I can't get this code to run.  I declared an EditText variable because Eclipse complained without it but I didn't really know why as I am not trying to edit any text.  I am just trying to push buttons by sending a TAB to move the focus, another code to press the button, and using other keys to start other activities.  The net was fatal exception and the app exited.  This code looks very similar to what I am using except onKey vs getKeyCode. I would like to try the different approach but need a bit of help to get it running.

Comment: where are you exacly getting your keyevent from? is it a simple button in your app? by the way, you are right, this code gets attached to an EditText since I assumed you want to catch the key event from there. But with a simple EditText field on the screen this works fine...

Comment: My key event comes from a bluetooth mouse-presenter.  The jave code I listed will display what the key code is in the Toast.  The translation of what these codes mean is given in the link in my post under "according to this" (click on "this").  I have checked these codes with known codes that come from the presenter such as volume-up, which is 24.  The pressing of the bluetooth device is intercepted by the app and various things happen as you can see from my code.  I have just three keys now with the 4th being the one I cannot get control of as it causes the tablet to leave my app

Comment: oh I understand, whilst I do not know about the BT mouse-presenter I would assume that ALT does not change the key code, in many systems the ALT is checked as a modifier of state for every key. So I expect you need to get the even that your ALT is pressed at all, independent of which other key is pressed. In that sense ALT is very different from Shift. I would expect the same to be true for Ctrl.

Comment: I am sure if I could block the META_LEFT (getKeyCode() = 117) I would be happy.  The question is how can I do that?